# How to integrate yahoo mail service in my Android application?

Tags: android

hi all I want to integrate yahoo mail service in my android application. After search much on google I didn't get proper tutorial for that please anyone provide me any link or suggestion which helpfull for me

Comment: Your question is too vague. Yahoo is a company. What service of Yahoo do you wish to integrate? What have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry my effort by which ZI can't explain you but I want to open yahoo mail services after login

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see above soure code its working fine and download **Oauth** Libary .

```
import oauth.signpost.OAuth;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthExpectationFailedException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthMessageSignerException;
import oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthNotAuthorizedException;
import oauth.signpost.signature.HmacSha1MessageSigner;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.synapse.selfervices.R;

public class YahooScreen extends Activity {
    private static final String REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL ="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token";
    private static final String ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL ="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_access_token";
    private static final String AUTHORIZE_WEBSITE_URL ="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/request_auth";
    private static final int PIN_DIALOG = 0;
    String CALLBACK_URL = OAuth.OUT_OF_BAND; // this should be the same as the
    // SCHEME and HOST values in
    // your AndroidManifest.xml file
    String CONSUMER_KEY = "";//
    String CONSUMER_SECRET = "";
    private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer myConsumer;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthProvider myProvider;
    private String requestToken;
    private String accessToken;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            callOAuth();
            showDialog(PIN_DIALOG);
            // createPinDialog().show();
    }

    private void callOAuth() {
            try {
                    // retrieve the consumer token and then sign it
                    myConsumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY,
                                    CONSUMER_SECRET);

                    myConsumer.setMessageSigner(new HmacSha1MessageSigner());

                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    // retrieve the provider by using the signed consumer token
                    myProvider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(
                                    REQUEST_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_ENDPOINT_URL,
                                    AUTHORIZE_WEBSITE_URL, client);
                    myProvider.setOAuth10a(true);
                    String aUrl = myProvider.retrieveRequestToken(myConsumer,
                                    CALLBACK_URL);

                    requestToken = myConsumer.getToken();
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(aUrl)));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ex.getMessage(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.e(ex.getMessage(), ex.toString());
            }
    }

    // this is the callback function that will run when oauth authenticates
    // successfully
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            System.out.println("OnNewIntent...");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OnNewIntent - It works!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // whatever you want to do after authenticating goes here ....
    }

    AlertDialog createPinDialog() {
            LayoutInflater factory = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            // LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.pin, null);
            final EditText pinText = (EditText) textEntryView
                            .findViewById(R.id.pin_text);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Twitter OAuth PIN");
            builder.setView(textEntryView);
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            if (pinText != null)
                                    gotOAuthPin(pinText.getText().toString());
                            onResume();
                    }
            });
            return builder.create();
    }

    private void gotOAuthPin(String pin) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("yahoo",
                            MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            try {
                    myProvider.retrieveAccessToken(myConsumer, pin);
                    accessToken = myConsumer.getToken();

            } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthNotAuthorizedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (accessToken != null && accessToken.length() > 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Authorized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(
                                    "http://social.yahooapis.com/v1/user/profile?format=json");
                    StringEntity body = null;
                    /*
                     * try { body = new StringEntity("city=hamburg&label=" +
                     * URLEncoder.encode("Send via Signpost!", "UTF-8")); } catch
                     * (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) { // TODO Auto-generated catch
                     * block e1.printStackTrace(); }
                     * body.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                     * request.setEntity(body);
                     */

                    try {
                            myConsumer.sign(request);
                    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (OAuthExpectationFailedException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (OAuthCommunicationException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println("Sending update request to Fire Eagle...");

                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpResponse response = null;
                    try {
                            response = httpClient.execute(request);
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    Toast.makeText(
                                    this,
                                    "Response: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
                                                    + " " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Not Authorized", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case PIN_DIALOG:
                    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.pin, null);
                    final EditText pinText = (EditText) textEntryView
                                    .findViewById(R.id.pin_text);
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setTitle("OAuth PIN");
                    builder.setView(textEntryView);
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                            int whichButton) {
                                                    if (pinText != null)
                                                            gotOAuthPin(pinText.getText().toString());
                                            }
                                    });
                    return builder.create();
            }

            return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }}
```

Comment: where to download Oauth Library.. can pls tell me..do you any demo of the yahoo integration for android.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply do have any full example of yahoo login for android...

Comment: Hi Rstar, Can you plz share the whole Demo app of integration with yahoo in to android application? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you plz share your layout files for this example?